# How to get Z ordering windows event for SWT Shell?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, citrix, xendesktop

I have one RCP based application which creates SWT shell and windows to show some real time information. When we use that application in XenDesktop Citrix Mode, I don't get to know if my SWT shell is covered by some other application launched on that XenDesktop like notepad.
I want to get some events when some other application is obscuring my SWT windows and when that application is completely moved out of my SWT window basically Z ordering events for windows. So that I can decide to show/hide my real time information accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that is not possible with SWT. It does not offer API to obtain the bounds of shells *outside* of the current application.

Your only choice here would be to access the platforms native features to obtain this information.

This article about SWT custom widgets also has a brief introduction on how to integrate with native code: https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm

Comment: Thanks, can you please provide any link how can I do that using native features. I need it for Windows only and its enough for me to get to know when my window gets overlapped by some other window. Right now I don't want any coordinates to know how much area is being overlapped.

Comment: Please see the amended answer.